# Scanning folders using lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to get the name of all the file saved in two folders, the name are saved as :

```
1.lua  2.lua  3.lua 4.lua and so on
```

the folders name are :

```
 first folder :   "/const/" 
 second folder:   "/virt/"
```

what I'm  trying to do is only get the number of the files and this works but not  in the right order, when I get the `17` file for example I get the 17th delivered from the function before the  15 and this causes for me a problem here the code of the function that I'm using :

```
local virt_path = "/virt/"
local const_path = "/const"
local fs = require "lfs"

local const = {}

for num = 1, (numberoffile)do   -- numberoffile is predfined and can't be change 
    const[num] = assert(
        dofile (const_path .. mkfilename(num)),
        "Failed to load constant  ".. num ..".")
end

local function file_number()  --this is the function that causes me a headach
    local ci, co, num = ipairs(const)
    local vi, vo, _   = fs.dir(virt_path)
    local function vix(o)
        local file = vi(o)
        if file == nil then return nil end
        local number = file:match("^(%d+).lua$")
        if number == nil then return vix(o) end
        return tonumber(number)
    end
    local function iter(o, num)
        return ci(o.co, num) or vix(o.vo, num)
    end
    return iter, {co=co, vo=vo}, num
end
```

As I said the function delive the  need return values but not the right Arithmetic order.

any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: You have 2 variant: 1. get all files in table, sort and iterate over this table; 2. iterate over number(1..N) and check if this file exists (this works if you have not holes)

Comment: @moteus could you give a concrete example of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my `path`[1] library.

1 We fill table with filenames

```
local t = {}
for f in path.each("./*.lua", "n") do
  t[#t + 1] = tonumber((path.splitext(f)))
end

table.sort(t)

for _, i in ipairs(t) do
  -- do work
end
```

2 We check if files exists

```
for i = 1, math.huge do
  local p = "./" .. i .. ".lua"
  if not path.exists(p) then break end
  -- do work
end
```

[1] https://github.com/moteus/lua-path